# Error message: Not enough input arguments

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-guide, numerical-methods

I'm trying to make my own function in matlab to solve for a system of ordinary differential equations, , here is the code:

```
function dw = fun(t,w)
n = 17;
c = 1;    h = 1/n;    r = (c/h)^2;
Id = ones( n - 2, 1 );      Id_off = ones( n - 3, 1 );
Z = zeros( n - 2, n - 2 );

M = diag( -2*r*Id ) +  diag( r*Id_off,  1 ) + diag( r*Id_off, -1 );
M = [Z eye( n - 2, n - 2 ); M Z];

v = zeros( 2*n - 4, 1 );
a = 0;    b =0;
v(n - 1) = r*a;     v(end) = r*b;

dw = M*w + v;
end
```

when I run the m file it give me the error message: "Not enough input arguments"

How can I fix this poroblem?
Thanks in advance

Comment: What command line do you enter to call your matlab file?

Comment: when I press F5 I get the error

Comment: If you have a .m file with a function, let's say `foo.m`, to call this function you must enter foo(arguments). What do you enter, that's my question

Comment: I call ff(t,w), but I got a message "Undefined function or variable 't'"

Comment: You must define the variables that you call as input of your functions of course. Anyway, you should read [Matlab Documentation](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-functions-in-files.html)  and [Matlab Tutorial](http://fr.mathworks.com/help/matlab/getting-started-with-matlab.htmll), it does contain the basis you need to know about the langage